# Bootstrap Modal Width Overflow issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have tried to set width and overflow properties to the span element so that the maximum width applies, but for some reason it is not working.

Here is the jsFiddle of the issue I am facing: http://jsfiddle.net/nyonfvsy/2/

```html
<div data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade" id="searchPO" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Post Office Lookup</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Destination Post Office</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" class="bigdrop" id="postoffice" name="postoffice" style="width:250px" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Zips Served</label>  <span id="lookup_zipsserved"> 894,895,896,897,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,951,952,953,954,955,956,957,958,959,960,961,962,963,964,965,966,967,968,969 </span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Zip codes, should not overflow the modal.

Comment: are the amount of zip codes going to cahnge or is it always this list?

Comment: Yes, the amount of zip codes will change.

Comment: see my answer below I hope this helps

Comment: if you can mark as answer i'm trying to get reduced adds and am really close :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css rule

```
#lookup_zipsserved{
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```